# Send binary data as HTTP and pass firewall

Tags: firewall

My game communicates with server through 4567 port using TCP custom binary protocol and some clients cannot play game. I think that is because of firewalls.

Later I will use 80 port and want to know: does firewall intruse into transmitting data and is there possibility that he will block non-HTTP data? If it is, how can I send my binary data within HTTP and will not firewall block even such data?

Thank you.

Comment: Ports and data aren't related, so there should be no problem at all in switching to port 80. Firewall on the other hand most surely can block your traffic no matter what, but the question is a bit too generic for more details than what's already been said below.

Answer (score 2):

Depends whether you want to ACCEPT INCOMING connections or just want to use port 80 for OUTGOING connections. Most Firewalls block any incoming connections by default (plus most home-routers are configured to do so, too).

For outgoing connections, however, the default behavior of the most popular Firewalls is to block and ask the user for permission for the program, unless it is run with administrative privileges (in which case the user already had to grant the program almost full control over the computer anyway). But it depends on the Firewall in question.